# How to set sonarqube to analyze remote code from TFS filesystem?

Tags: tfs, sonarqube

I want to use `sonarqube` to analyze code that is stored in the `TFS` file system, which is in a remote machine.

So I have on:

```
machine A -> sonarqube

machine B -> TFS
```

This `machine B` contains three projects: `proj1`, `proj2`, and `proj3`

I need to configure `sonarqube` to "look" to `machine B` to those 3 projects and analyze them.

On my `sonar-project.properties` file I have the following:

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube
sonar.projectKey=my:proj1
# this is the name displayed in the SonarQube UI
sonar.projectName=proj1
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# sonar sources
sonar.sources=. <----what do I need to put here?

# Language
sonar.language=cs

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

What do I need to put on the field `sonar.sources` ? I thought I just needed the `IP/Port` location of the TFS root of the three projects ...Something like: http://192.168.1.102:3000 ?

```
sonar.sources=http://192.168.1.102:3000 # doesn't work :(
```

But it doesn't work either...

Also, how can I set the:

`sonar.projectKey` and `sonar.projectName` to analyze all three projects? In my above example is just looking at `proj1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS doesn't have a file system. It has source code stored in a repository (either TFVC or Git). If you want to perform SonarQube analysis, you'll need to get the code out of the repository first. The most common approach is to integrate static analysis into your automated build process.

If you're using TFS 2015 or Team Services, there are [SonarQube tasks readily available](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/24/build-tasks-for-sonarqube-analysis/) to run SonarQube analysis.